# EdiatbleImageWebpart Hidden in MasterPageTemplateHeader for Content Editor page Kentico 9

Tags: templates, master-pages, hidden, kentico

I am trying to add Editable Zone to Header part of Master Page template. This editor zone contains EditableImage and CSS Menu. I want to make this Header to appear on every page of my site. And EdiatbleImage in this header to be available to Edit for content editors.

When this page is opened in Edit mode CSS menu is visible but EditableImage is overlapped by Edit toolbar of Kentico. Please refer to image.

Kindly let me know.

1. Is it possible to add EditableImage in Master Page template in Kentico and make it available for content 
   Editors to Edit.
2. Kentico edit toolbar in Page edit mode can be repositioned.

Best Regards,
Manmath

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1: Yes, it's possible to add an Editable Image to the master IF you are using Portal method, if you are using aspx.net+portal the master page template (on the root node) is rather fixed.  This is why Kentico recommends Portal only method, and i do as well.

2: You more want to edit your content's position in edit mode rather than the bar.  When in "Edit mode" there is a special css class that is added to the body tag (I believe "EditMode" is the class name).  You then add special css to adjust the display to account for edit mode issues, such as

```
/* Bump my menu down 20 pixels if in edit mode */
.EditMode .MyMenu {
  margin-top:20px;
}
```

Otherwise you won't run into these problems if you log into the Kentico portal and edit your pages through the "Pages" module.